# Matplotlib Obscure Tick Behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I observe some obscure behaviour of the ticks in a `matplotlib.pyplot` log-log plot.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

dtFractions = [1/1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8]

L2Err   = [4.41669808e-06, 1.10121946e-06, 2.78272254e-07, 8.18570087e-08]
LInfErr = [7.68589519e-05, 2.00625677e-05, 6.05176778e-06, 2.55658820e-06]

InchesX = 7
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Blue_RGB   = [(0, 84/256, 159/256)]
Petrol_RGB = [(0/256, 152/256, 161/256)]

### ACTUAL PLOTTING: Infty errors ###
ax.scatter(dtFractions, LInfErr, label = r'$e^\infty$', color = Blue_RGB)
ax.plot(dtFractions, LInfErr, color = Blue_RGB[0], linestyle='dashed')
ax.scatter(dtFractions, L2Err, label = r'$e^2$', color = Petrol_RGB)
ax.plot(dtFractions, L2Err, color = Petrol_RGB[0], linestyle='dashed')

ax.loglog(dtFractions, np.multiply(1e-5, np.power(dtFractions, 2) ), linestyle='dotted', 
          label = r'$\mathcal{O}\left(\Delta t^2\right)$',
          color = 'black') # Order two line fitted 

# Turn on logscale (no native support for logarithmic scatter)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Delta t^\mathrm{Eff}_S$')

### GRID SECTION ###
ax.grid(axis ='both', which='major', alpha=0.1, linewidth = 1.5, color ='black')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)  # Hide grid behind bars

### LEGEND SECTION ###
ax.legend(loc = "upper left")

### TICKS SECTION ###

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which = 'both', bottom=False)

ax.set_xticks(dtFractions)

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', size=0)
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0) 

ax.set_xticklabels([r"$1$", r"$1/2$", r"$1/4$", r"$1/8$"])

### TITLE SECTION ###
plt.title(r"$l^\infty$ Error for CEE: Isentropic Vortex on Uniform Grid")

# Scale while preserving aspect ratio
width, height = fig.get_size_inches()
factor = InchesX / width
fig.set_size_inches(width * factor, height * factor)

plt.tight_layout()  # Title, labels, ... to screen
plt.savefig('Convergence2DComprEulerVortex_PERK.pgf', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.show()
```

This produces

[image]

Note in particular the strange additional ticks.

If I add one more custom tick, i.e.,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

dtFractions = [1/1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16]

L2Err   = [4.41669808e-06, 1.10121946e-06, 2.78272254e-07, 8.18570087e-08, 42]
LInfErr = [7.68589519e-05, 2.00625677e-05, 6.05176778e-06, 2.55658820e-06, 42]

InchesX = 7
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Blue_RGB   = [(0, 84/256, 159/256)]
Petrol_RGB = [(0/256, 152/256, 161/256)]

### ACTUAL PLOTTING: Infty errors ###
ax.scatter(dtFractions, LInfErr, label = r'$e^\infty$', color = Blue_RGB)
ax.plot(dtFractions, LInfErr, color = Blue_RGB[0], linestyle='dashed')
ax.scatter(dtFractions, L2Err, label = r'$e^2$', color = Petrol_RGB)
ax.plot(dtFractions, L2Err, color = Petrol_RGB[0], linestyle='dashed')

ax.loglog(dtFractions, np.multiply(1e-5, np.power(dtFractions, 2) ), linestyle='dotted', 
          label = r'$\mathcal{O}\left(\Delta t^2\right)$',
          color = 'black') # Order two line fitted 

# Turn on logscale (no native support for logarithmic scatter)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Delta t^\mathrm{Eff}_S$')

### GRID SECTION ###
ax.grid(axis ='both', which='major', alpha=0.1, linewidth = 1.5, color ='black')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)  # Hide grid behind bars

### LEGEND SECTION ###
ax.legend(loc = "upper left")

### TICKS SECTION ###

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which = 'both', bottom=False)

ax.set_xticks(dtFractions)

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', size=0)
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', width=0) 

ax.set_xticklabels([r"$1$", r"$1/2$", r"$1/4$", r"$1/8$", r"$1/16$"])

### TITLE SECTION ###
plt.title(r"$l^\infty$ Error for CEE: Isentropic Vortex on Uniform Grid")

# Scale while preserving aspect ratio
width, height = fig.get_size_inches()
factor = InchesX / width
fig.set_size_inches(width * factor, height * factor)

plt.tight_layout()  # Title, labels, ... to screen
plt.savefig('Convergence2DComprEulerVortex_PERK.pgf', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.show()
```

Then everything works as expected:

[image]

Is this a bug? I tried also the second version and then setting `xlim` to something fitting - the obscure ticks are arising again.